# Is this sentence correct? "中国发送给我们国家很多帮助"

Tags: writing-critique

大家好!

Hi, can you please tell me is this sentence correct?
请问，这个句子对吗 ?:

> 在疫情其间中国发送给我们国家很多帮助。

谢谢 !

Comment: You should probably state the original English of what you were aiming for with the Chinese.

Comment: “其间” is wrong. It should be “期间”.

Comment: `发送` sounds odd, `给予很多帮助`

Answer (score 1):

> 在疫情其(期)间中国发送给我们国家很多帮助。

The sentence is wrong.  The collocation 发送帮助 isn't appropriate.  We can say 给予帮助.  So, 在疫情其(期)间中国给予我们国家很多帮助 or  is correct.

Comment: 明白了，非常感谢你的帮助 ~~

Answer (score -1):

在疫情期间中过帮助了我们的国家。 Is also okay. 发送 is used to say for physical objects.